# Add freeform shape option - PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

In my powerpoint I opened an image, I clicked on image, I went to Format-->Crop-->Crop to Shape, but I didn't find the Freeform option. How can I add it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you'd like to see this feature added, please visit https://powerpoint.uservoice.com and request it. MS developers monitor this site and features that get lots of votes receive lots of attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The Freeform crop shape has been removed.